# Inserting into hashmap, accounting for duplicates in Set?

Tags: java, hashmap, set

So to my knowledge duplicates are not allowed in a Java set. Why then in this code snippet does the code seem to try to take account of duplicates?

```
public static Subarray findSmallestSubarrayCoveringSet(List<String> paragraph,Set<String> keywords) {

   Map<String, Integer> keywordsToCover = new HashMap<>();
   for (String keyword : keywords) {
      keywordsToCover.put(keyword,
      keywordsToCover.containsKey(keyword)? keywordsToCover.get(keyword) + 1: 1);
   }
```

Why not just have keywordsToCover.put(keyword,1) inside the for loop?

Comment: You're right, the code doesn't make sense. Where is it from?

Comment: https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ux3PCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=keywordsToCover+%3D+new+HashMap&source=bl&ots=XlidougYH6&sig=plWNqvW6_Wfesq0sDpeyZ5caClg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwja296k1JbXAhVHM5oKHdUgAWAQ6AEIKDAB#v=onepage&q=keywordsToCover%20%3D%20new%20HashMap&f=false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct here, the call `keywordsToCover.containsKey(keyword)` would *never* be *true*. It just seems that whoever wrote the code didn't understand what is the purpose of a `Set` or they have mistakenly done so (though that's unlikely). thus just the call `keywordsToCover.put(keyword,1)` would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, as it says in [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html):

> a `Set` is a collection that contains no duplicate elements.

Who ever wrote that sample is unaware of this fact.

There will *never* be a case where `keywordsToCover.containsKey(keyword)` returns *true*, unless `keywordsToCover` is initialized (outside of the method) as static and is *not* reconstructed every time `findSmallestSubarrayCoveringSet` is called.